# MongoDB Find, Data float, Schema build

Tags: jquery, json, mongodb, backend, database

I passed a json array with obj from frontend, and parse it to an array, and I create a database with a json object. How can I find the username? Or is it any batter way I can pass and get data between frontend and database? Please

frontend js file use jquery post to backend.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    url: 'users',
    data: {Data:JSON.stringify(stickersData)}
});
```

Schema

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var usersData = new Schema({
        'usersdata': Object
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('usersData', usersData);
```

//---------------------------------------------------------
backend use bodyparser getting data from frontend post.

```
  usersData.create({'usersdata':(JSON.parse(stickersData))});
```

//------------------------------------------------------
Here is what I got in the database

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5939164c7e7fc9242400cce4"
    },
    "usersdata": [
        {
            "bgcolor": "rgb(204, 255, 204)",
            "left": 234.28756713867188,
            "top": 56.287567138671875,
            "content": [
                "  some note21",
                " some note22"
            ],
            "tag": [
                "  tag22 ",
                " tag23 "
            ],
            "username": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "bgcolor": "rgb(255, 255, 204)",
            "left": 64.06646728515625,
            "top": 49.06646728515625,
            "content": [
                "some note1",
                "some note2"
            ],
            "tag": [
                "tag1",
                "tag2"
            ],
            "username": "bbb"
        },
        {
            "bgcolor": "rgb(204, 204, 255)",
            "left": 403.43243408203125,
            "top": 47.43241882324219,
            "content": [
                "  some note33",
                " some note34"
            ],
            "tag": [
                " tag32 ",
                " tag33 ",
                " tag 555 "
            ],
            "username": "ccc"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: `"username": " aaa    \n      "` that looks like a mistake. Not only is there leading and trailing space but also a newline character. I would strongly suggest sanitizing your data to remove those erroneous characters.

Comment: I know, thats what I got from JSON.parse method.

Comment: I think this problem can be fixed by regular expression match.

Comment: I am trying to use  db.usersdatas.find({"usersdata":[{"username": " aaa    \n    "}]}).pretty() to find username but doesnt get anything..

Comment: You should fix your data rather than try and match on it. Yes a regular expression would match, but you should not store like this is the recommendation.

Comment: I fixed it. I updated the new result in the database in the question. Do you have any idea to find users and find tag data. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wrap your users in a `usersdata` property?

Comment: I just have no idea to post data from view to backend. Then wrap up in the view js file, post the whole obj  with schema  var usersData = new Schema({
        'usersdata': Object
    });

Comment: Thanks for your guys help. I rebuild the schema. as var usersData = new Schema({
    'username':String,
    'usersdata':[{
    'tag':[String],
    'content':[String],   
    'top':Number,   
    'left':Number,   
    'bgcolor':String,  
    }]
});
..Looks like more reasonable. Now I can search by username.